# getting sets of rows from Azure table storage via pk&rk

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have a list of partitionkey , rowkeys that I need to fetch. The only way I can think of getting them is by doing a query like this

```
(partitionkey="pk1" and Rowkey="rk1) or (partitionkey="pk2" and Rowkey="rk2)
```

this works but is limited to 7 rows (15 clauses in a query)

Anybody know how to do more

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no better solution for this particular query. You'are basically doing a A*B+C*D+E*F+... This polynomial cannot be simplified.

If your scenario allows, try to use other queries. For example, query only a single entity using PK + RK. Use multiple requests to query multiple single entities. Use a single request to query all entities within a partition (based on some filters, such as range), and so on.